# Using Leaflet.Path.Drag plugin with React Leaflet

Tags: javascript, plugins, leaflet, es6-modules, react-leaflet

Leaflet.Path.Drag is a plugin to the Leaflet library. It works by patching the global `L` instance that Leaflet adds to the window. This mechanism works fine when Leaflet and the plugin are incorporated in an app via script tags. But in a modern TS/React app that uses ES6 modules, simply installing the two packages and then importing them doesn't achieve the needed plugin integration. To get the plugin to work I've tried the following in my Reach Leaflet app, as recommended [here](https://asymmetrik.com/ngx-leaflet-and-leaflet-plugins/):

```
// Import Leaflet into L 
import * as L from 'leaflet';

// Import the plugin library so it will modify L
import 'leaflet-path-drag';

const createDraggablePolygon = () => {
  const geometry = {
    type: "Polygon",
    coordinates: [[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]]]
  }
  const geoJson = L.geoJSON(geometry, {});
  // plugin should add 'dragging' property to the GeoJSON object
  assert("dragging" in geoJson);
}
```

This doesn't work either (the assertion fails). Suggestions?

One clarification: I am not trying to build a plugin for React Leaflet (at least if I can avoid it). In my case it's fine if the behaviors exposed by the plugin are only available through Leaflet elements and not through the React Leaflet library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The solution above actually patches the Leaflet library correctly. The reason the `geoJSON` layer didn't have the `dragging` property was that it extends `LayerGroup` so you need to include an `onEachFeature` function in the options. The layers that Leaflet passes into that function are the ones that have been patched with the `dragging` property. So I needed something like this:

```
// Import Leaflet into L 
import * as L from 'leaflet';

// Import the plugin library so it will modify L
import 'leaflet-path-drag';

const initDraggableLayer = (feature, layer) => {
  // plugin adds 'dragging' property to this layer
  assert("draggable" in layer);
} 

const createDraggablePolygon = () => {
  const geometry = {
    type: "Polygon",
    coordinates: [[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]]]
  }
  const geoJson = L.geoJSON(geometry, {
    onEachFeature: initDraggableLayer
  });
}
```

Comment: Although adding an `onEachFeature` callback allows me to make the GeoJSON layer draggable, I still have a problem in using this capability within a React context: namely, that while I can bind handlers for events like `dragend` to the layer within the callback, I'm not able to do much with the data from those events. If I try to set state using a useState hook within the callback, Leaflet blows up with errors like: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'mouseEventToContainerPoint')`